# How to have a process automatically restart

Tags: server, python, restart

I have a simple home automation program written in Python that reads events from USB and sends commands to a server. It runs on a headless Ubuntu server. Basically, the program does a `while true` loop. Now if this program should be interrupted for whatever reason, I want it to automatically restart. A few moments or even minutes of down time would not be a problem. What is the easiest way to do this? I could write a cron job to check whether the program is still there, but is there another way to do this that I might not know about?

Comment: Yup, Upstart is what you want for now. There are others but Upstart is built-in and pretty simple. Note that this will change in newer versions of Ubuntu to Systemd.

Comment: Thanks, `upstart` will do what I need.